# Cannot send emails to yahoo using mailkit

Tags: yahoo, mailkit

I am creating a system that sends emails (pricing, orders, invoices, etc) to out customers. But due to the number of emails that ends up being, we hit limits when trying to send through gmail or any other mail client. And since these are all customer specific emails using a bulk sending client is not ideal.

So I have created a system using mailkit and others to send our emails from our own servers without needing to set up a relay or email server for sending. This works great with everyone (Gmail, outlook, etc) except for yahoo. For some reason when I connect and mailkit tries to switch to STL (via startstl) yahoo sends garbage and mail kit fails.

I have enabled all ssl and tsl protocols. And I have ServerCertificateValidationCallback always to return true. In fact ServerCertificateValidationCallback doesn't even get called.

The errors that are thrown start with:
A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception

then 
The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.

If I try to connect to any of the other SMTP ports 465 or 587 the system just hangs.

This all happens when connecting, before the email is sent. So it cannot be a DKIM issue. And the SPF record is set up correctly. We don't have the reverse dns setup because we plan on sending from multiple servers with different IPs.

I don't know why yahoo is being so difficult.

Tried talking with MailKit, tries allowing all TLS and SSL connections. Tried finding any YAHOO support.

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.LocalDomain = "MyDomain";

    // right now we don't care about all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => {
        return true;
    };
    client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11 |
    System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 |
    System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls |
    System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3 |
    System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl2;
    client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;

    client.Connect("mta6.am0.yahoodns.net", 25, false); //<--- fails here

    client.Send("test", fromMailBoxAddress, recipientsEmailBoxAddresses);

    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, I might have an idea why Yahoo is being so difficult - it's possibly your message construction.  Verify your MimeMessage has the same exact email address for your From and Sender addresses.  Ensure your ReplyTo only contains the Sender email address. *I had both the sender and recipient email addresses in the ReplyTo and Yahoo did NOT like that*. And, of course, you are using a Yahoo App password for authentication.  Once I made these two changes, Yahoo sent the email successfully.

**Settings**

```
client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
client.DeliveryStatusNotificationType = mail.DeliveryStatusNotificationType.Full;
await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
await client.AuthenticateAsync(yourEmailAddress@yahoo.com, yourYahooAppPassword);
await client.SendAsync(Message);
await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
```

**Research**

Bad message construction breaks one of Yahoo's many policies. This was ONLY happening with SMTP via Yahoo.  SMTP via Gmail and Outlook work fine.  I kept comparing a simple MailMessage with MimeMessage message construction.  MailMessage sent, MimeMessage failed, I kept getting a **550 request failed; mailbox unavailable** response from Yahoo every time with my MimeMessage.  I verified by using ProtocolLogger.  My **From** was empty and that is one issue, and, I had the recipient in my ReplyTo.  If I merely added the sender to the ReplyTo, it still throws that same 550 error.  I had to ensure the *sender* was the *only* email in the ReplyTo.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your imput. But I am not trying to send from Yahoo I am trying to send to yahoo. I have many clients that have yahoo email and I need to be able to send invoices and information to them. I am trying to send from an email server but yahoo rejects everything I try. Even though all the email testing sites give me a perfect 10.

Answer (score 0):

Use `client.Connect("mta6.am0.yahoodns.net", 25, SecureSocketOptions.None);` if you want to disable `STARTTLS` or use `client.Connect("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);` which works fine.

Not sure where you are getting "mta6.am0.yahoodns.net" from, but I can't even make a normal socket connection to that address.

Comment: I tried the SecureSocketOptions.None but then I get some error about users having complained about spam from my IP. I have never sent email from this IP and I checked all the black lists and I am no where on it.

Comment: mta6.am0.yahoodns.net came from their mx records.

Comment: Your SSL/TLS options aren't going to make or break any spam classification, so that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree. And I have submitted a case to Yahoo but I expect no response.

Comment: That is why I am trying to get the starttls working. I assume they won't allow anyone who is not using SSL to talk to the server and they are throwing a false positive when starttls is ignored.

Comment: Have you tried not enabling SSLv2 and SSLv3? You shouldn't be enabling those as they are insecure.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all of them at the same time as seen above and all of the one at a time. Same results.

Comment: You should probably also disable `SslProtocols.Tls` as that is also obsolete/insecure.

Comment: client.Connect("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.Auto) does work a as long as you have an account. But again I am trying to send to yahoo.com not route through yahoo. When I don't authenticate it says something about needing mail before recipients.

Comment: No, I'm saying DO NOT enable those. They may be forcing System.Security's SslStream to negotiate SSLv2 or SSLv3 with the server and then getting bad/broken data.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if that wasn't clear. I have tried each protocol one at a time, as well all of them at the same time. I assume that client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12; is the proper way to do that?

Comment: Yes, and as you used in your comment, I would only enable Tls11 and Tls12.

Comment: Yeah I tried that just now. No success.  client.Connect("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.Auto); almost worked, but it gave back the response 
S: 450 Requested mail action not taken: mailbox unavailable
S: 503 5.5.0 Need MAIL before RCPT
And I know the mail address is correct. I just emailed it from another account.

Comment: Get me a log of that: `new SmtpClient (new ProtocolLogger ("smtp.log"))`

Comment: Looks like yahoo's smtp server is a broken pile of garbage. MailKit clearly sent a `MAIL FROM` command which it is saying MailKit didn't.

Comment: Try disabling `PIPELINING` with the following statement before calling `Send()`: `client.Capabilities &= ~SmtpCapabilities.Pipelining;`

Comment: It is a little bit different but still no luck

Comment: It's effectively saying it will not send mail on your behalf... probably because it is not an @yahoo.com address.

Comment: Looks like it didn't even send the recipient email address that time. Just the from.

Comment: I am not trying to have them send email for me. I just want them to accept the email I am sending to them.

Comment: There has to be a way that servers send to them.

Comment: Yeah, that is probably because of the smtp.mail.yahoo.com only being used for routing. The MX records are probably used for receiving.

Comment: Oh, right, they are rejecting your message because you are connecting to smtp-mail.yahoo.com right now (which is their smtp server for yahoo users).

Comment: Well, with any luck they will respond to me at some point. Until then this project is dead in the water.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can I get you to delete the comments with my email address please.

Comment: Absolutely. Did I miss any?

Comment: Nope, Thanks for your help. This product is awesome by the way. If I figure out the problem I will make sure to post the solution.